# How can I get td first child value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where I want, for each row, get the first `td` and for this `td` I want the first `input` child value.

I'm able to get the markup for the input, but I can't extract the value.

Here is my code:

```
$('#table-unidades tr:not(:last-child)').each(function () {
        $('td:first-child', this).each(function () {
            var firstCell = $(this).children().eq(0);
            var text = firstCell.html();
            alert(text);
        })
    });
```

my alert outputs this:

```
<input type="text" name="unidades-first-td" value="UN - Unidade" disabled />
```

But all I want is the value.. I've tried with .text(), .val() , but it didn't work...

Comment: Try: `$('#table-unidades tr:not(:last-child) td:first-child').each(function () {alert(this.value);})`

Comment: `var text = firstCell.val();` should have worked.  Better construct a fiddle for better understanding.

Comment: @tewathia , it gives "undefined" for every iteration .. But the problem was solved, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Praveen , yup, I thought so too.. But it doesn't really work, I need the .find('input') before .val() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get value of input, then use [**`find()`**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find input field inside `td`

```
$('#table-unidades tr:not(:last-child)').each(function() {
    $('td:first-child', this).each(function() {
        var firstCell = $(this).children().eq(0);
        var text = firstCell.find('input').val();
        alert(text);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try this and get them all as an array once:

```
$("#table-unidades tr:not(:last-child)>td:first-child input:text:first-child")
                  .map(function () {return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var val = firstCell.find('input').val();
alert(val);
```

Comment: cause you use attr instead of val. +1 for using alert instead of console.log which is not native.

Comment: Ah ok. I think I misread the question (again). I'll update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use two each loops to find first child, also you must use `.val()` to get the value of an input, try this

```
$('#table-unidades tr:not(:last-child)').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).find('td:first input:first').val();
});
```

Comment: wow, nice, this is outputing one extra alert with "undefined", but it is working indeed, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the input element

```
$('#table-unidades tr:not(:last-child) td:first-child').each(function () {
    var firstCell = $(this).children('input');
    var text = firstCell.val();
    alert(text);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work this way, it outputs nothing.. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var trs = $("tr", ".my-table");
for(var i=0; i<trs.length; i++){
    var nval = $("td:first-child > input", trs[i]).val();
    console.log(nval);
}
```

1 don't care about the reputation. 
2 if it doesn't work, make it work.

Comment: are you here to help or to get reputation ?